# How to set content-type in Google Cloud Scheduler job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-cloud-functions, httprequest, google-cloud-scheduler

I currently have a cloud scheduler job with an http target and post method.

According to Google's documentation for the Cloud Scheduler:

> **Content-Type:** By default, the Content-Type header is set to "application/octet-stream". The default can be overridden by explicitly setting Content-Type to a particular media type when the job is created. For example, Content-Type can be set to "application/json".

I need to do almost exactly this, set Content-Type to "*application/json; charset=utf-8*", but I see no way of doing so. How do you "override it explicitly"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set headers with the CLI `gcloud scheduler jobs create http <NAME>`:

Windows Command-line Syntax:

```
--headers="{ \"Content-Type\": \"application/json; charset=utf-8\" }"
```

Linux Command-line Syntax:

```
--headers='{ "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }'
```

Documentation:

[gcloud scheduler jobs create http](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http)

In this answer I show another example so that you can see the options that you need to include with the command:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53182080/8016720

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ended up having to change the syntax slightly, don't know if I was doing something wrong, but the only syntax that finally worked was --headers="Content-Type=application/json" (I ended up ignoring the charset=utf-8 as it was only optional)