# How to add a JSON body on a HTTP POST request made with Cloud Scheduler? Will it add the "Content-Type": "application/json" header?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, http-post, google-cloud-scheduler

When you are creating a new cron job in **Cloud Scheduler**:

[image]

What should I add in the `body` field, in order to pass a parameter value:

What is the specification of that field? Should I write `JSON` in there?

Let's say I want to pass this `JSON` object:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Is the `"Content-Type": "application/json"` automatically added?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide the information you consider appropriate in the body field.

At least in the case of `AppEngineAppTarget`- probably the behavior will be the same for `HttpTarget`, as indicated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#AppEngineHttpTarget) when describing the `headers` field, they indicate that if the job has an body, Cloud Scheduler sets the following headers:

> Content-Type: By default, the Content-Type header is set to "application/octet-stream". The default can be overridden by explictly setting Content-Type to a particular media type when the job is created. For example, Content-Type can be set to "application/json".
> ...

AFAIK, it is not possible to provide the `Content-Type` or any other custom header from the Google Cloud Web console, but you can use the `gcloud` CLI if you need to. Please, see the [relevant documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http). Pay special attention to the `OPTIONAL FLAGS` section, and within it, to the `--headers`, `--message-body` and `--message-body-from-file` flags. Your command should look something like:

```sh
gcloud scheduler jobs create http job-name \
  --schedule="0 */3 * * *" \
  --uri="http://your.url.com" \
  --http-method=POST \
  --headers="Content-Type: application/json" \
  --message-body="{\"field1\":\"value1\",\"field2\":\"value2\"}}"
```

Please, see also this related SO questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718268/how-to-set-content-type-in-google-cloud-scheduler-job) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53181297/verify-http-request-from-google-cloud-scheduler/53182080#53182080), they could be of help.

Comment: Thank you so much! Didn't know it was possible to add headers through `gcloud`. And how about when you inspect a cron job you've created with `gcloud` and have set some `headers`. How do they appear on the Cloud Scheduler Console? I mean, how can one verify which jobs have which headers? I guess `gcloud` has some kind of `--list` flag that might log all these details.

Comment: You are welcome @cbdeveloper. I honestly does not know if the Google Cloud Web console provides that level of detail for the job - I will dig into it, but the `gcloud` CLI provides the [`describe`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/describe) and [`list`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/list) commands that can be use to get information about a certain job or list, and optionally filter, sort, etc, your jobs, respectively.

Comment: Thank you again. That works fine. I just changed the headers flag to this: `--headers Content-Type=application/json`. They should really add a `headers` config to the Console.

Comment: Yes, I think so @cbdeveloper.

Comment: The header has been added to the web interface